# Force gatling.io test to fail connections after a certain duration

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling

Is there a way to force a gatling test to consider connections that have been active longer than a certain duration to have failed?

For instance, I have a test that will create 400 users/second for 60 seconds. However I am having the test "hang" indefinitely.

```
================================================================================
2016-04-13 08:08:25                                         200s elapsed
---- Full Chain test -----------------------------------------------------------
[##############################################################------------] 84%
      waiting: 0      / active: 3728   / done:20362 
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=20362  KO=0     )
================================================================================
```

As you can see, the 60 second test, +/- a few seconds for the final requests to complete, has gone on for 200 seconds (this is before killing it). The "active" number has remained at 3728 since the 65 second mark.

This duration goes against all the timeouts I can see in the gatling docs, and setting my own timeouts doesn't appear to do anything. Here's my reference.conf

```
gatling {
  http {
    ahc {
      requestTimeout=7000
      maxRetry=0
      sslSessionTimeout=7000
    }
  }
  data {
    noActivityTimeout=5
  }
}
```

Has anyone figured out a way to get around this issue?

Comment: try`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` as start parameter.
see: http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/project/faq.html, last point

Comment: Added that to my sbt file `javaOptions += "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"`. No luck, still running into the issue.

Comment: you could try `sbt -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true ...` on commandline, or are you sure, that the way you tried to set the arguments is correct?

Comment: tried `sbt -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` just to make sure, no dice. Thanks for the suggestion though, always good to sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to Gatling 2.2.0 that we've just released. There's a good chance it fixes your bug.

Comment: I updated to 2.2.0, however the issue still remains (though only at slightly higher numbers now `sos.inject(constantUsersPerSec(1200) during(120 seconds) randomized)` where `sos` is a scenario that does a simple get request with two parameters that are pulled randomly from a csv file.

Comment: Then if you can provide a reproducer, please report and open an issue.